# Using pre-trained BERT embeddings as input to CNN with tensorflow.keras results in ValueError

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am brand new to NLP and deep learning, so I have what is (likely) a very basic problem.

I am trying to create a binary classifier based on pre-trained BERT embeddings as the features. So far I have successfully created the embeddings, and have built a simple Sequential() model with tensorflow.keras. The code below works:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    Dense(4, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (768,)),
    Dense(4, activation = 'relu'),
    Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')])

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam',
              loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
              metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

What I would like to do is adapt this code to now be a CNN. However, when I add a convolutional layer, I get an error:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    Conv1D(filters = 250, kernel_size = 3, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1, input_shape = (768,)),
    GlobalMaxPooling1D(),
    Dense(4, activation = 'relu'),
    Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')])

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam',
              loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
              metrics = ['accuracy'])

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-59695050a94e> in <module>()
      3     GlobalMaxPooling1D(),
      4     Dense(4, activation = 'relu'),
----> 5     Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')])
      6 
      7 model.compile(optimizer = 'adam',

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py in assert_input_compatibility(input_spec, inputs, layer_name)
    178                          'expected ndim=' + str(spec.ndim) + ', found ndim=' +
    179                          str(ndim) + '. Full shape received: ' +
--> 180                          str(x.shape.as_list()))
    181     if spec.max_ndim is not None:
    182       ndim = x.shape.ndims

ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv1d_2 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 768]
```

Here is what the data I am using look like.

Features:

```
train_features[0]

array([-4.97862399e-01,  1.49541467e-01,  5.81708886e-02,  1.63668215e-01,
       -2.77605206e-01,  3.57868642e-01,  1.70950562e-01,  2.69330859e-01,
       -3.29369396e-01,  2.12891083e-02, -4.02462274e-01, -1.98120754e-02,
       -2.18944401e-01,  4.34780568e-01, -2.75409579e-01,  2.03015730e-01,...

train_features[0].shape
(768,)
```

Labels:

```
train_labels.iloc[0:3]
turnout       
0        73446    0
1        53640    1
         16895    1
Name: turnout, dtype: int64
```

Any advice is much appreciated. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2D Convolutions need 4D inputs: `(batch_size, width1, width2, channels)`.

Your data is a single array with shape `(batch_size, 768)`. If you really want to use a convolution (if you think there might be a spatial relation in your data), you need to shape it properly before feeding it to your model.

1D Convolutions need 3D inputs: `(batch_size, length, channels)`.